# SBT, dependencies, classpath and editors

Tags: intellij-idea, ivy, sbt

I recently updated my sbt setup to version 0.11. As you may know, new SBT uses .ivy2 folder to store/cache all the retrieved jar files. I am using IntelliJ and I would like to know what is the recommended way of importing dependencies to the editor's classpath.

One option is to manually visit .ivy2 folder and select the dependencies. Is there a better/easier way to doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume you use the [SBT-plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=5007). According to the instructions on the linked page:

> After each change to your dependencies, run gen-idea in the SBT Console. When prompted, reload the project.

I usually run 
`gen-idea no-classifiers no-sbt-classifiers`
(see under "Usage" on [github](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/)). IntelliJ (11 RC) will then ask you to reload the project, which is usually quite fast. Then the references to your SBT dependencies will be available.

Comment: More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250318/how-to-create-sbt-project-with-intellij-idea and https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea

Answer (score 0):

You can try [IvyIDEA plug-in](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=3612).