# Getting IntelliJ IDEA understand SBT dependencies

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have SBT and Scala installed and things work well.

Now I have an IntellIJ IDEA project, which works otherwise OK except that dependencies which are downloaded into `/Users/MyName/.ivy2/cache/` are not understood.

I tried setting the cache path as a source folder:

[image]

but still things don't work out:

[image]

As you can see, `org.eclipse` is in red color meaning it can't find it. It must be inside that `.jar` file I showed on the left.

I just want to update/download dependencies using SBT, and then get the compilation to work in IntelliJ IDEA with those dependencies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create SBT project with IntelliJ Idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250318/how-to-create-sbt-project-with-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin for SBT.  Then you can run "gen-idea" from the sbt command line and it will generate the metadata files used by IDEA.  These files contain the locations of jars as SBT uses them so that IDEA will know where the dependencies are, just like SBT.

Comment: How do I use this? I have set the `addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.1.0")` and tried running `gen-idea` and I get `[error] Not a valid command: gen-idea`.

Comment: My bad! I didn't realize the file `plugins.sbt` had to be under a folder called `project`, I thought it meant my project folder.

Comment: Will this automatically update dependencies when new ones have been added to the build.sbt file or will the gen-idea need to be run every time something has been added to that file?

Comment: what if I'm using SBT plugin for Idea 12?

Comment: @fohtoh you will need to run `sbt gen-idea` every time you change build.sbt

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Idea refuses to use dependecies in External Libraries in the Project window, and marks classes from import statements red, while sbt compiles just fine. Yet i could just ctrl-click into the package in External Libraries in the Project window, idea refuses to use classes in the package!