# IDEA says a dependency is missing, SBT disagrees

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

my issue seems similar to [Getting IntelliJ IDEA understand SBT dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228754/getting-intellij-idea-understand-sbt-dependencies)

except I'm using sbt 1.4.4 ,and the plugin suggested in that question no longer appears to work (it requires sbt version 0.13.x, and last commit to that plugin was 7 years ago)

is there anything similar that might work with more recent versions of sbt, or some other way to get intelliJ to work?

It only seems to affect 2 dependencies, all other dependencies works fine, thing is, i really need those 2 dependencies.
I'm on Linux, should it matter, a colleague opened the same code on Mac, and had no issues, however I've tried clearing every cache i could think of, reinstalled IDEA, rebooted twice, changed idea settings to use sbt shell for everything, nothing and everything in between. I've tried to rebuild with sbt version override enabled and/or disabled.

I dont get any errors from intelliJ rebuilding the project, but the editor still insists that some dependencies does not exist!

I'm out of ideas, how can I fix IDEA?

Comment: Does the problem persist if you delete `~/.config/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.1` and `.idea` within project? I do sometimes, but rarely, also experience this problem.

Comment: yes, problem persists unfortunately.

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using?

Comment: I'm using Idea Ultimate 21.1, build #UI-211.6693.111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First identify the path to problematic dependencies by executing

```
sbt 'show dependencyClasspath'
```

which prints out something like

```
Attributed(/home/picard/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/typelevel/mouse_2.13/1.0.0/mouse_2.13-1.0.0.jar)
```

Next  in the following order

1. `sbt clean` the project
2. invalidate caches
3. Exit  IntelliJ
4. nuke your project's `.idea` directory.

Now say `mouse` was the problematic dependency, then remove it with

```
rm -fr /home/picard/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/typelevel/mouse_2.13
```

Finally reimport the sbt project which, if you have the shortcut setup, from project's root directory

```
idea .
```

and let sbt refetch the missing dependencies and let IntelliJ reindex them.

Comment: this..kinda solved it. I no longer have the issue with the original 2 packages. However I now have a similar issue with a third package. I guess I'll just repeat the process until it works

Comment: @AndersMartini Maybe try nuking the whole coursier cache. It is harsh approach and all your projects will have to redownload dependencies, but it does seem corruption is in dependencies cache.

Comment: yep! that did the trick! many thanks! you earned your bounty :)

Comment: for completeness sake, I'd suggest you include in your answer the macOS path for the corsier cache:  ~/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1. I'm sure this issue can in theory occur on macbooks as well

Comment: @AndersMartini 'show dependencyClasspath' should reveal the correct path on each system.

Comment: fair enough, that it should

Comment: @AndersMartini Do you have any idea what might have corrupted the cache? For example, did your machine lose power suddenly during indexing?

Comment: not a clue, haven't had a power outage in ages. can't think of any other abnormal event that could have caused it either, bar maybe a VPN connection drop at worst. doesn't seem like it would cause this tho...