# Adding a third-party library to Scala project (Idea 12 with SBT plugin)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm developing a Scala application in IntelliJ Idea 12. I have sbt plugin for Idea installed (Setting -> Plugins -> Browse repositories ...). Now I want to use some extra libraries for Scala, let's say one of them is https://github.com/stevej/scala-json. So I downloaded zip file from its source code from its github repository.

What do I do next? What is the standard way of adding a third-party library to Scala project using Intelli Idea 12 **with SBT plugin** installed?

Comment: The standart way to adding libraries is to write library meta in SBT build file, so SBT may resolve dependencies on it's own. After `sbt update` you have to issue `sbt gen-idea` to get familiarize IDEA with downloaded jars. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250318/how-to-create-sbt-project-with-intellij-idea

Comment: @om-nom-nom but, as I said, I have sbt plugin installed in Idea. can't your solution be simplified because of this? I don't know how exactly, though.

Comment: and also, there is no file *.sbt in my project.

Comment: IIRC, the main goal of third party plugin is to provide embedded REPL -- it doesn't do anything about dependency resolving. IDEA team working of full integration of SBT right now and said to deliver such feature quite soon. See ["General usage instructions"](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pluginId=5007) section

Comment: @om-nom-nom, I didn't ask about that.

Comment: *What is the standard way of adding a third-party library to Scala project using Intelli Idea 12 with SBT plugin installed?* Current version of IDEA SBT plugin do not make a ANY difference from the point of dependency resolution. You had to switch back to [the usual SBT stuff](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/index.html) and then convert it in a format that IDEA understands via `sbt gen-idea` every time you make changes to build definition.

Comment: it says "[error] Not a valid command: gen-idea"

Comment: you have to setup sbt-idea plugin first, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250318/how-to-create-sbt-project-with-intellij-idea) I've already provided in first comment contains instructions

Comment: @om-nom-nom your first comment should have been the answer ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this in the .sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(                            
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "1.0.0",
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.9.1",
    "net.sf.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "2.3",
    "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math3" % "3.0"              
)
```

you have to create your .sbt file in your project directory if you don't have one.

This is a quick [tutorial](http://grosdim.blogspot.ch/2013/01/quick-sbt-tutorial.html) on sbt (and [another one](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html))

Comment: where try? what do I have to do exactly?

Comment: @Luther not only create this file and populate with dependencies, but also issue `sbt gen-idea`. Otherwise, IDEA will know nothing about this definitions.

Comment: is it necessary to specify a version of a dependency (% "3.0")?